# Scheduled task disappeared from the Task Library the next day

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

We have a Win7 Pro 32-bit system where we want to schedule a daily backup to run at 1pm. The task was created yesterday morning. It ran fine that afternoon. It didn't run today. When the Task Scheduler is opened, the task is no longer in the library.

Interestingly, schtasks.exe still knows about it, and the XML job file is still located in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` as it should be.

Where do we start to diagnose and resolve this?

#### Update

Here's a couple of additional tidbits that might narrow the scope but Murphy says are probably red herrings:

- At an administrator command prompt, `schtask /run /tn "\my task"` says "Catastrophic failure" among other confidence inspiring words.
- There is a VPN involved, provided by OpenVPN. The task had a condition set to run only if that network connection is available. When I compare the XML for the missing task to XML for a newly created task, I find that the network ID has changed. This might be the root cause. We'll know more tomorrow after the VPN has come and gone as it normally does over night.
- This all works as expected and without any trouble on a second identical Win7 Pro 32-bit computer, as well as on a Win7 Pro 64-bit system.
- The backup tool is a homegrown beast, but from the Task Scheduler's point of view it boils down to running a batch file at least once a day.